# A simple String manipulation program but i dont quite understand why it is behaving the way it is

Tags: c, string

It works completely fine for first `printf "dello"` statement but I don't know why it does not print `" ello"` in the second `printf` statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OKAY

int main() {
    char str[10] = { "hello" };
    if (str[0] = 'h')
        str[0] = 'd';
    printf("%s", str);
#ifdef OKAY
    if (str[0] = 'h')
        str[0] = '\0';
    printf("%s", str);
#endif
}
```

The output of the above program is

```
dello
--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.379 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `if(str[0]='h')` is an *assignment* that is implicilty tested for being non-0 so it is always `true`. Did you mean `if(str[0]=='h')`?

Comment: You are confusing `==` with `=`. Your expected output will never print because the string will be terminated at the first character.

Comment: Besides that incorrect assignment, if you want to get a space you should assign a space `' '` instead of 0 byte.

Answer (score 1):

`if (str[0] = 'h')` does not test if `str[0]` is equal to `'h'`, it sets `str[0]` to `'h'` and then checks if the result differs from `0`, which is true (the result is `'h'`). Hence the code is equivalent to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define OKAY

int main() {
    char str[10] = { "hello" };
    str[0] = 'h';
    str[0] = 'd';
    printf("%s", str);
#ifdef OKAY
    str[0] = 'h';
    str[0] = '\0';
    printf("%s", str);
#endif
}
```

So it prints `dello` then an empty string, ie: nothing more.

You meant to write this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define OKAY

int main() {
    char str[10] = { "hello" };
    if (str[0] == 'h')
        str[0] = 'd';
    printf("%s\n", str);
#ifdef OKAY
    if (str[0] == 'h')
        str[0] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", str);
#endif
}
```

Which also prints `dello` twice, each on a separate line

Comment: and what about ```if (str[0] =='d') ``` in ifdef OKAY then why dont it print ``` ello```

Comment: @Raon: because `str[0] = '\0'` make `str` an empty string.  Did you mean `str[0] = ' ';` ?

Comment: yes, but is there any difference between null(space) and null character

Comment: @Raon: the null character, aka the null byte, is a `char` with the value `0`, usually written `'\0'`, present at the end of C strings, whereas a null pointer is a pointer that does not point to any valid object, compares equal to `0`. `(void *)0`, `(char *)0` are examples of null pointers as is `0` cast to any data pointer type. The preferred way to specify a null pointer is via the `NULL` macro defined in multiple standard headers (`<stddef.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<string.h>`...)  There is no such thing as a *null space*: `' '` is a character constant representing the space character

Answer (score 0):

`=` and `==` are two different things.

```
if(str[0]='h')
 str[0]='d';
```

should be

```
if(str[0]=='h')
 str[0]='d';
```

`==` checks for equality.  `=` assigns a value.

This is a very common problem, and most compilers will warn you about it.  For example, if you're using gcc:

```
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:8:5: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
     if(str[0]='h')
     ^
```

The unfortunate part is that gcc is assuming that you mean to do that, and the warning is that you should have parentheses around it to clarify that you meant to do it even though it looks wrong. In your case, it *is* wrong.

Comment: However, the result would still be truthy, isn't it?

Comment: sorry for trouble but i meant '==' rather than assingnment